# Is xtend BCAA really effective?

Tags: workout, supplements

I am planning to use Xtend BCAA and whey isolate from [MyProtein](https://www.myprotein.co.in/sports-nutrition/impact-whey-isolate/10530911.html?variation=10889148)

So if anyone can tell me that whether it is good to take it?

Or i should consider BCAA and whey from any other brand which is very good?

Comment: Define "good". Supplements satisfy a need. If you don't have that particular need, you shouldn't be taking the supplement. If you don't know if you have a need for it, consult a doctor.

Comment: @Alec Actually i dont have such doctor in my city who would be able to advice me on taking supplements or not so i am just not sure whom to ask because my coach have already recommended me to take BCAA and Whey protein and apart from that i am following some good body builders on instagram and have seen them taking BCAA and whey protein and seen recommending this things too